# Displaying 3-D scatter plot w/ Color Dependent on Data

Tags: matlab, plot, scatter-plot

I have a large set of data that I've collected that I'd like to display in a 3-D scatter plot. The data is contained in a text file.

The data is organized like so

```
1 1 1 10.8
2 1 1 3.4
4 1 1 6.1
8 1 1 4.5
1 2 1 7.8
...
8 8 8 11.9
```

The first three tokens in each line should represent (x,y,z) points. In the 3-D scatter plot, there should be a dot for each of these points.

The color of the dots depends on the fourth token. Basically, the closer the fourth parameter is to the max value, the closer it will be to the color red. The close the fourth parameter is to the min value, the bluer it will be.

I'm pretty sure that the scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C) function does this, but I'm not an expert.

Here's what my data variable contains:

[image: Data Variable]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (assume `data` is the array you presented in your question):

```
x = data(:,1);
y = data(:,2);
z = data(:,3);
s = ones(size(data,1), 1) * 20; %sizes of markers
c = data(:,4); %color data

scatter3(x,y,z,s,c);
colorbar;
```

Or you can simply do it inline:

```
scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3),ones(size(data,1), 1)*20,data(:,4));
colorbar
```

Comment: Nice. Just needs one change: `ones(size(data,1))` --> `ones(size(data,1), 1)`

Comment: @Phonon Doesn't work. x, y, z, and c contain an Mx1 array of elements, with c containing floating point numbers, and x,y,z containing the integers. Are you sure those are the right parameter? Matlab is giving me an error at the line where the scatter3 function is called.

Comment: @Phonon It still doesn't work. I have a screenshot of what my data variable contains. Perhaps you misunderstood exactly how I organized my data.

Comment: @seljuq70 I did misunderstand. Will fix the answer in a minute.

Comment: @Phonon Got it, small tweak, but you're solution works for everyone else.

Comment: @Phonon: actually you can just give a scalar value for size. IMO it would look better if you used filled points. Also you should explicitly specify the jet colormap to be clear: `scatter3(x,y,z,100,c,'filled'), colormap(jet), colorbar`